# finding index of an object inside an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, indexof

i have this

```js
arr = [{name: 'pippo',lastname: 'p'},{name: 'mickey',lastname: 'mouse'}]
x ={name: 'mickey', lastname: 'mouse'}
arr.indexOf(x)
```

why arr.indexOf(x) returning -1?
Is there another solution to find the index of an object inside of an array of objects?

Answer (score 5):

Since you have array of objects, it does not work straight forward using `indexOf()` to get the index of that specific object in that array. You need to use `findIndex()` so that when there is a matching object in the array, it returns the respective index of that object, else `-1`.

```js
arr = [{name: 'pippo',lastname: 'p'},{name: 'mickey',lastname: 'mouse'}]
x ={name: 'mickey', lastname: 'mouse'}
console.log(arr.findIndex((obj) => obj.name == x.name && obj.lastname === x.lastname));
```

Comment: @RaydenC you can tick mark the answer if that was helpful to you. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

indexOf() checks the reference of the object inside the array. Since you are making a new object and passing it as an argument to indexOf() it doesn't match the reference of object inside the array so it fails.

```
let arr = [{name: 'pippo',lastname: 'p'},{name: 'mickey',lastname: 'mouse'}]
arr.indexOf(arr[1])
```

Whereas this code will return 1 as expected as the reference is same.

Solution as given by @Ankit

```
arr = [{name: 'pippo',lastname: 'p'},{name: 'mickey',lastname: 'mouse'}]
x ={name: 'mickey', lastname: 'mouse'}
console.log(arr.findIndex((obj) => obj.name == x.name && obj.lastname === x.lastname));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple loop

```js
arr = [{name: 'pippo',lastname: 'p'},{name: 'mickey',lastname: 'mouse'}]
x ={name: 'mickey', lastname: 'mouse'}


for(let i=0;i< arr.length;i++){
  if(JSON.stringify(arr[i])===JSON.stringify(x))
   console.log(i)
}
```